# XML file processing subtags or make the number of subtags consistent

Tags: python, html, xml, python-3.x, python-2.7

The contents of the processed XML file are as follows：

```
<dblp>
<incollection> 
<author>Philippe Balbiani</author> 
<author>Valentin Goranko</author> 
<author>Ruaan Kellerman</author> 
<booktitle>Handbook of Spatial Logics</booktitle> 
</incollection>
<incollection> 
<author>Jochen Renz</author> 
<author>Bernhard Nebel</author> 
<booktitle>Handbook of AI</booktitle> 
</incollection>
...
</dblp>
```

**The format content is as shown above extracting the "author" tag content and the "booktitle" tag content they are all in the "incollection" tag traversing each "incollection" tag and having multiple "author" tag contents with a "booktitle" Label content forms corresponding tuple.**

my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(getfile()), 'lxml')
res = soup.find_all('incollection')
author = []
booktitle =[]

for each in res:
    for child in each.children:
          if child.name == 'author':
                author.append(child.text)
          elif child.name == 'booktitle': 
                booktitle.append(child.text)
elem_dic = tuple(zip(author, booktitle))
```

The result I made is:

```
('Philippe Balbiani', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Valentin Goranko', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Ruaan Kellerman', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
```

**How can I modify it to achieve the desired result?like this:**

```
('Philippe Balbiani', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Valentin Goranko', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Ruaan Kellerman', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics')
('Jochen Renz', 'Handbook of AI')
('Bernhard Nebel', 'Handbook of AI')
```

**Or you can add the "booktitle" tag in each "incollection" tag to the same number as the "author" tag.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming BeautifulSoup 4.7+

This is actually pretty easy to do. In this example, I'm using selectors (I know selectors are normally associated with HTML, but you can use them in XML for this kind of task. Here we say we want all of the `incollection` tags who have a direct child (`>`) of tags that are either `author` or `booktitle` (`:is(author, booktitle)`). This gives us only the tags we are interested in.  Then we simply gather the authors until we see a booktitle, and then create the entries for that book. Afterwards we reset and gather info for the next book:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = """
<dblp>
<incollection> 
<author>Philippe Balbiani</author> 
<author>Valentin Goranko</author> 
<author>Ruaan Kellerman</author> 
<booktitle>Handbook of Spatial Logics</booktitle> 
</incollection>
<incollection> 
<author>Jochen Renz</author> 
<author>Bernhard Nebel</author> 
<booktitle>Handbook of AI</booktitle> 
</incollection>
</dblp>
"""

author = []
elem_dic = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'xml')
for child in soup.select('incollection > :is(author,booktitle)'):
    if child.name == 'author':
        author.append(child.text)
    else:
        elem_dic.extend(zip(author, [child.text] * len(author)))
        author = []

print(tuple(elem_dic))
```

output

```
(('Philippe Balbiani', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics'), ('Valentin Goranko', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics'), ('Ruaan Kellerman', 'Handbook of Spatial Logics'), ('Jochen Renz', 'Handbook of AI'), ('Bernhard Nebel', 'Handbook of AI'))
```

---

You don't have to use selectors though:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

markup = """
<dblp>
<incollection> 
<author>Philippe Balbiani</author> 
<author>Valentin Goranko</author> 
<author>Ruaan Kellerman</author> 
<booktitle>Handbook of Spatial Logics</booktitle> 
</incollection>
<incollection> 
<author>Jochen Renz</author> 
<author>Bernhard Nebel</author> 
<booktitle>Handbook of AI</booktitle> 
</incollection>
</dblp>
"""

author = []
elem_dic = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'xml')
res = soup.find_all('incollection')
for each in res:
    for child in each.children:
        if not isinstance(child, Tag):
            continue
        if child.name == 'author':
            author.append(child.text)
        else:
            elem_dic.extend(zip(author, [child.text] * len(author)))
            author = []

print(tuple(elem_dic))
```